# Why is the probability of this problem not P(A)P(B)?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I'm dealing with a sample problem where I want to work out the probability of a fair coin toss landing *heads* and a fair die roll landing *6*. We are then told that **at least** one of those events has happened.

Why is the probability of this not as simple as *P(C)P(D) = 0.083*? How would one work out the correct probability using the Bayes theorem?

Thanks

Comment: What if you already rolled 6? Obviously, the probability to get the required event is different now.

Answer (score 1):

Because now you have the additional information that at least one of those events has happened.

Hence the corresponding probability is $$\frac{P(CD)}{P(CD^c) + P(C^cD) + P(CD)}=\frac{P(CD)}{1-P(C^cD^c)}$$

That is I have excluded the possibility of $C^cD^c$ from happening.

Try to compute this quantity.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $P(C \cap D)= P(C)P(D)$. However in this case you are not asking that question , your question here is:
$P(C \cap D \mid \text{ at least one of the events happened} )$ . In this new probability space the events are not independent.
$$P(C \cap D \mid \text{ at least one of the events happened} )=P(C \cap D \cap \text{ at least one of the events happened} ) \frac{1 }{P(\text{ at least one of the events happened}) }$$
The first term is $0.083$, the second term is equal to
$$ P(C \cup D)=P(C)+P(D)-P(C \cap D)$$ which is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}- 0.083$